# How to build functional sunspot model on the ground with high-power plasma burners in the strong magnetic field as conference paper?

Tags: plasma-physics, sunspots

I need to build functional sunspot model on the ground with high-power plasma burners in the strong magnetic field as conference paper.

What I get is light-weight  plasma, as exactly plasma is.

But I need to generate dense structure fluid, as depicted in the following images:

[image]

[image]

### --

Comment: You want a sunspot _analog_, or actual sunspot conditions?

Comment: I have studied plasma generation and there is no way to get plasma desnse like the magnetic fluid (image No.1).
Now I study how to turn magnetic fluids into plasma

Comment: I discussed the problem with my friends

https://solarchatforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=39378

Comment: Science Advances

Reconnection-driven energy cascade in magnetohydrodynamic turbulence
Chuanfei Dong https://orcid.org/0000-0002-8990-094X , Liang Wang https://orcid.org/0000-0003-4821-3120, Yi-Min Huang https://orcid.org/0000-0002-4237-2211, Luca Comisso https://orcid.org/0000-0001-8822-8031, Timothy A. Sandstrom https://orcid.org/0000-0002-0490-5494, and Amitava Bhattacharjee https://orcid.org/0000-0001-6411-0178Authors Info & Affiliations
Science Advances
7 Dec 2022
Vol 8, Issue 49
DOI: 10.1126/sciadv.abn7627

Comment: The world's largest turbulence simulation unmasks the flow of energy in astrophysical plasmas 

https://www.pppl.gov/news/2022/worlds-largest-turbulence-simulation-unmasks-flow-energy-astrophysical-plasmas

Comment: So sunspots can be modelled with magnetic fluids on the ground, at ambient temperature, since magnetic fluid matches hydromagnetic features of the hot and dense solar plasma

Comment: https://mami.u-strasbg.fr/index.php/magnetic-fluids-and-microfluidics-a-short-review/

https://www.aalto.fi/en/news/tuning-a-magnetic-fluid-with-an-electric-field-creates-controllable-dissipative-patterns

https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=Magnetic+Fluid+Sculpture+Art&form=IRIBIP&first=1

Comment: https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abi8990